# Adding a Relationship Property to a return node using C# neo4j client?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have this query where two nodes of the same label could have a relationship:

```
Match (n:MyObject)-[r:SOME_RELATIONSHIP]->(n1:MyObject) Return n, n1
```

The :SOME_RELATIONSHIP has properties that I wanted to access in a cypher query using C#. While I can return the following:

```
Match (n:MyObject)-[r:SOME_RELATIONSHIP]->(n1:MyObject) Return n, n1, r.propertyToGet
```

Is it possible to return say n1 with an additional property from the relationship? So say n1 has 4 properties, it will be 5 with the new property coming from the relationship?

eg:

```
{
  "n1" : {
    "originalprop1": "somevalue1",
    "originalprop2": "somevalue2",
    "originalprop3": "somevalue3",
    "originalprop4": "somevalue4",
    "newprop": "value_from_relationship",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This query uses Cypher's [map projection](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/maps/#cypher-map-projection) syntax to combine the properties of the 2 maps the way you want:

```
MATCH (:MyObject)-[r:SOME_RELATIONSHIP]->(n1:MyObject)
RETURN n1{.*, newProp: r.value_from_relationship}
```